# Make a code for cashier in java. With math.round it gives me more and with math.floor sometimes less what i should do?

Tags: java

I need to write a java program that computes change will be given for a sales transaction.

It can only dispense 20s, 10s, 5s, 1s, quarters, dimes, nickles, and pennies.

I make it and its all okay but i have a problem. When i put math.round some they go round up like 1.6 in 20euros and it gives wronge change. And if i put math.floor it give less after in coins. What im doing wrong? 
Here is my code:

public class MyCurrencyCashier {

```
public static void main (String [] args){

float  twentyEuro;
float  tenEuro;
float  fiveEuro;
float  oneEuro;
float  twentyFiveCent;
float  tenCent;
float  fiveCent;
float  oneCent;
float change; //declares how much change is given in return

change = Float.parseFloat(args[0]); //read the change from the command line

twentyEuro = (change / 20);
if (twentyEuro >= 1) {
    change = (change % 20);
    System.out.println("€20 bill: " + Math.round(twentyEuro));
} else {
    System.out.println("€20 bill: 0");
}

tenEuro = (change / 10);
if (tenEuro >= 1) {
    change = (change % 10);
    System.out.println("€10 bill: " + Math.round(tenEuro));
} else {
    System.out.println("€10 bill: 0");  
}

fiveEuro = (change / 5);
if (fiveEuro >= 1) {
    change = (change % 5);
    System.out.println("€5 bill: " + Math.round(fiveEuro)); 
} else {
    System.out.println("€5 bill: 0");
}

oneEuro = (change / 1);
if (oneEuro >= 1) {
    change = (change % 1);
    System.out.println("€1 bill: " + Math.round(oneEuro) + "\n"); 
} else {
    System.out.println("€1 bill: 0");
}

twentyFiveCent= (change / 0.25f);
if (twentyFiveCent >= 1) {
    change = (change % 0.25f);
    System.out.println("25_cent_coins: " + Math.round(twentyFiveCent));
} else {
    System.out.println("25_cent_coins: 0");
}

tenCent = (change / 0.10f);
if (tenCent >= 1) {
    change = (change % 0.10f);
    System.out.println("10_cent_coins: " + Math.round(tenCent));
} else {
    System.out.println("10_cent_coins: 0");
}

fiveCent = (change / 0.05f);
if (fiveCent >= 1) {
    change = (change % 0.05f);
    System.out.println("5_cent_coins: " + Math.round(fiveCent));
} else {
    System.out.println("5_cent_coins: 0");
}

oneCent = (change / 0.01f);
if (oneCent >= 1) {
    change = (change % 0.01f);
    System.out.println("1_cent_coins: " + Math.round(oneCent));
} else {
    System.out.println("1_cent_coins: 0");
}

}//end main
```

}// end class

I put 32.12 and i expect

€20 bill: 1

€10 bill: 1

€5 bill: 0

€1 bill: 2

25_cent_coins: 0

10_cent_coins: 1

5_cent_coins: 0

1_cent_coins: 2

But i get this:

€20 bill: 2

€10 bill: 1

€5 bill: 0

€1 bill: 2

25_cent_coins: 0

10_cent_coins: 1

5_cent_coins: 0

1_cent_coins: 2

Comment: I put 32.12 and i expect
€20 bill: 1
€10 bill: 1
€5 bill: 0
€1 bill: 2

25_cent_coins: 0
10_cent_coins: 1
5_cent_coins: 0
1_cent_coins: 2

I get
€20 bill: 2
€10 bill: 1
€5 bill: 0
€1 bill: 2

25_cent_coins: 0
10_cent_coins: 1
5_cent_coins: 0
1_cent_coins: 2

Comment: €20 bill: 1
€10 bill: 1
€5 bill: 0
€1 bill: 2

25_cent_coins: 0
10_cent_coins: 1
5_cent_coins: 0
1_cent_coins: 2

Comment: Okay wait a moment

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to worry about rounding these numbers at all; by default, if you divide two numbers and cast/coerce them to `int`, they will automatically be the floor of the quotient.

In other words, if you perform `(int) (32.12/20)`, you're going to get 1 back.  This is accurate, since there is only the possibility of 1 20 euro bill existing in that amount.  The same would be true if you did `(int) (39.99/20)`, since only one 20 euro bill exists in that amount, too.

You can use this information to carve out the specific monetary amounts you need; more importantly, they do *not* need to be stored in a `float` at all since they're whole numbers.

The below is a sample of where you can do with this.  I leave the rest of the values as an exercise for the reader.

```
int twentyEuro;
float change;
change = Float.parseFloat(args[0]); //read the change from the command line

twentyEuro = (int) (change / 20);
change = change - twentyEuro * 20;
System.out.println("€20 bill: " + twentyEuro);
System.out.println(change);
```

Comment: Okay thaks. I get it. You are correct. But if we should put math.round?

Comment: @T.Hehe:  No, you really don't need it.  Anyone suggesting that you would need to round when integer division already does the rounding for you is genuinely misleading.  I will say that things do get dicey when you start talking about values less than 1 (meaning you'd need to do a bit more work to get those values out, which I *believe* you already do), but you should **not** need to use `Math.round` for this at all.

Comment: Okay and how to print zero if its not have change in some

Comment: @T.Hehe: It's the same principle - if you have `(int) (19.99/20)` you'll get 0, since you're not able to get an entire 20 euros out of 19.99.

Comment: I see. Okay i will fix the entire code and i will reply to you if i have problem. Thanks again.

Comment: @T.Hehe: I strongly encourage you to go figure it out from here.  This is probably the biggest hint I can give you without writing the entire thing myself, and neither of us want that.